# Memory Leak with NSXMLParser on IPhone

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, nsxmlparser, nsmutablestring

below is my code, Leaks says I am getting a memory leak around NSMutableString alloc method.  I am sure it is something I simply overlooked, let me know if anyone has any thoughts.  Thanks!

---

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{

    if (!currentValue) {
        currentValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:[string length]];
    }

    [currentValue setString:[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];

}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"phone"]){

      currentAgent.phone = currentValue;
    }

    [currentValue release];

    currentValue = nil;

}
```

---

-Agent is a custom object that was created when the class was initialized.  The XML is valid and has all the appropriate begin/end tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking over this code, I think it's more likely that your Agent class is leaking phone. Assuming Agent uses `retain` for the phone property, this will cause the phone to persist longer than it should.

The creator of the object gets "credited" with the leak, even if the extra retain is somewhere else.

In other words, in Agent:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    self.phone = nil;
    // anything else you need to do
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Steven, I knew it was something that I simply overlooked. It appears that my dealloc for the Agent class had releases for all properties accept the phone one.  I modified and the Leak appears to be resolved.  Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I've reached the point where I really enjoy memory problems. :)